# When taking values from a pandas dataframe what is the most eloquent way to remove the [''] around each value?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list

I apologise if this is a stupid question but i can't find an obvious answer.

I have some code that is just iterating through a column I have taken from a pandas dataframe and pulling out the unique names. The column looks something like this:

```
FileNames

file1
file1
file2
file2
file2
file3
file3
```

I just want to make a txt file that reads:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Instead I am getting a text file that reads:

```
['file1']
['file2']
['file3']
```

The code I am currently using is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


List = []


for line in range (len(Dataframe)-1):
    if Dataframe.iloc[line].values == Dataframe.iloc[line+1].values:
        Currentline = Dataframe.iloc[line].values.tolist()
    elif Dataframe.iloc[line].values != Dataframe.iloc[line+1].values:
        List.append(Currentline)
    else:
        print('Either I have finished or something has gone wrong')

myfile = open('text.txt', 'w')

for item in List:
    myfile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Whilst this whole code works fine the list that is outputting has square brackets and '' marks around each item. Now I can just remove these with the strip function but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this?

Also what is it about the way I am doing things that makes it output in the current format?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good way to do it, but if you need to ged rid of the parentheses, you coud do `List.append(*Currentline)` instead of `List.append(Currentline)`, because you are appending a list instead of a value, so a good idea would be to unzip it first

Comment: Can you add the definition for `Dataframe` in your code?

Comment: Also, why not just pandas `.to_csv()`? Also, if you want the unique elements from a series, you don't need a loop to do it. You can just put them in a python set. Or use `.unique().index`.

Comment: Instead of using ```tolist()``` method, take the first element of ```values``` as there is one element per line as I understand : ```Currentline = Dataframe.iloc[line].values[0]```

Comment: why not just drop duplicates, `df['FileNames'].drop_duplicates()` ..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `unique` from pandas

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"FileName": ['file1', "file2", "file1", "file1", "file3", "file2"]})
print(df)
#     FileName
# 0  file1
# 1  file2
# 2  file1
# 3  file1
# 4  file3
# 5  file2
df['FileName'].unique()
# array(['file1', 'file2', 'file3'], dtype=object)
```